# Qt disable QShortcut to pushbutton when button is disabled

Tags: qt, qt4

I'm a beginner to QT.  I have used QShortcuts to bind keys to pushbuttons.

```
QShortcut *sb_0 = new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_0), this);
connect(sb_0, SIGNAL(activated()), ui.b_0, SIGNAL(clicked()));
```

However, when when b_0 is disabled, the shortcut still works.

```
ui.b_0->setEnabled(FALSE);
```

I would like, somehow, that the shortcut be disabled when I disable the pushbutton.  I am thinking that I could disconnect the QShortcut from the QPushbutton; however, this doesn't seem like it would be the best idea.

Also, I'm wondering if it'd be possible to have it so that when the key '0' is pressed, the button goes down (gets pushed down), and then when it is released, the button goes back to normal.  So basically, pushing '0' is like holiding down left-click on b_0.

If this has already been answered (I couldn't find an answer to this), please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just call setShortcut on the QPushButton?

```
void  setShortcut ( const QKeySequence & key )
```

This is provided on the [QAbstractButton](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qabstractbutton.html) class, so it might not be the most obvious thing to find in the documentation.

```
 ui.b_0->setShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_0));
```

That should do the trick.  The button already handles what should happen if the button is not enabled.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks you for the advice.  You're right, I didn't find it because I didn't know to look in the QAbstractButton class.  I will certainly be using what you have suggested!

For the record though, does the button have a different signal that I could have connected to (instead of 'clicked()') to make this work?  Is there a simple way to make my approach work?